# My timer's thread may be cheating on him with Thread.sleep?

Tags: java, multithreading

So essentially I am concerned that my timertask's `run` method is not being called after 10 minutes because I am putting the main thread to sleep for 10 seconds to avoid crazy CPU usage to just run through an empty while loop all day. Here is the code for the java main method.

```
 private static boolean testDone = false;
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
        final int minutes = 10;
        final StressTest test = new StressTest(someParams);

        test.start();

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                testDone = true;
                int completedSynths = test.stop();
                System.out.println("Completed Synths: " + completedSynths);
                System.out.println("Elapsed Time in Minutes: " + minutes);
                System.out.println("Throughput (synths/min): " + completedSynths/minutes);

            }}, minutes*60*1000);

        while(!testDone)
        {
            System.out.println("Still not done... sleeping for 10 secs....");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }

        System.exit(0);
```

Even crazier, the `System.out` in the `while` loop is never printing. What have I done??

EDIT: TO add pseudocode for StressTest object

```
public class StressTest 
{

    private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    private volatile int completedSynths = 0;

    private volatile boolean shouldStop = false;

    private Thread[] threads;

    /**
     * Instantiate a new StressTest object.
     * 
     * @param threadCount number of concurrent threads to be polling server
     */
    public StressTest(int threadCount)
    {
        threads = new Thread[threadCount];
    }

    public void start()
    {
        System.out.println("Starting Stress Test....");

        for(int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
        {
            Runnable synthCaller = new SynthApiCaller();
            threads[i] = new Thread(null, synthCaller, "SynthThread" + i);
            threads[i].run();
        }
    }

    public int stop()
    {
        System.out.println("Stopping Stress Test...");
        shouldStop = true;

        return completedSynths;
    }

    private String randId()
    {
        return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
    }

    private class SynthApiCaller implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            while(!shouldStop)
            {
                try 
                {
                            //this class makes an HTTP request to a server and then writes result to a file
                    MyClass.writeFile( "someFileLoc/file.data");
                    completedSynths++;

                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -r " + fileLoc);
                    System.out.println("Synth # " + completedSynths);
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Thread terminated...");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am concerned that my timertask's run method is not being called after 10 minutes because I am putting the main thread to sleep for 10 seconds

The `Thread.sleep(...)` in your main thread will not affect the running of the `Timer`.  If the timer is not running after 10 minutes then is it possible that `test.stop()` is blocking?

It is important to realize that if the test is started in the main-thread and then is being stopped in the `Timer` thread then some synchronization will be necessary.  I assume the test is running in another thread.  You probably will need it to be synchronized then inside of the `Timer` thread you would call something like:

```
synchronized (test) {
    test.start();
}
```

If you are new to Java synchronization, there are some [good tutorials online](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

If you are wondering whether or not the timer is being called at all, I'd set a break point inside your timer task where is sets `testDone = true` and see if it gets there. 
Here's a [good tutorial of using a debugger in eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html).

> Even crazier, the System.out in the while loop is never printing. What have I done??

As @assylias mentioned, the `System.out(...)` in your while loop not showing up must mean that  `testDone` is set to true.  Since `testDone` is being updated and accessed in different threads, you need to make sure it is also `volatile`.

---

I just ran your code sample without the `test.start()` and `stop()` and it seems to work fine.  The problem may be in your `test` code.

```
Still not done... sleeping for 10 secs....
Still not done... sleeping for 10 secs....
...
Completed Synths: 1
Elapsed Time in Minutes: 10
Throughput (synths/min): 0
```

---

Now that you've added more code, here are some comments:

- `completedSynths++;` should be changed to be an `AtomicInteger`.  ++ is not an atomic operation so even tho the field is volatile, multiple threads can overwrite each other's increment.
- If you are trying to wait for the threads to complete, instead of sleeping for 10 minutes, I'd recommend calling `thread[i].join()` with the threads.  Even better would be use an `ExecutorService` and use the `awaitTermination(...)` method.
- You call `shouldStop = true;` and then return the `completedSynths;`.  You may want to wait for the threads to finish or something.
- I'd not pass in a `null` `ThreadGroup` to the `Thread` constructor.  Just use the constructor without the `ThreadGroup`.

Comment: Alright, let me try and put together some pseudocode representing the test object. It might take a second as there is a bunch of code in there that I would rather people not see (And its useless for the understanding). Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: Alright, I edited to include the test class which also has some threading components. Possibly, there is something in there that is not allowing the threads to close, thus the main method never terminates?

Comment: Point 1 is taken, although given what Myclass.writeAudio does (takes a long time, like 1 minute), it is extremely unlikely for that to occur. 2 - I am little unclear as to what you mean about this one. "joing the threads"? and what do you mean by "instead of sleeping for 10 minutes"? Is this method of timers changing boolean flags not correct in some way?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest making testDone volatile. As it is, I don't see anything forcing changes to testDone to be visible to reads in threads other than the one making the change.